# ocultar la ruta de una imagen php

Tags: php, imagen, rutas

E buscado la manera de disfrazar la ruta de una imagen y lo que e encontrado es que se puede con base64 aun que esto suele ser un problema para imágenes pesadas

y en la plataforma de twitch sus emotes los tienen en un archivo .0 (punto cero) como la siguiente ruta

https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/112290/1.0

y muestra lo siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que se de eso es que lo usan para ocultar la verdadera fuente de la imagen y quiero saber como podría yo hacer algo así para tener oculta mis rutas

Comment: Tal y como lo citas, esas URL corresponden a URL que genera el CDN de twitch para identificar recursos estáticos (como las imágenes).

Comment: La única forma de "ocultar" imágenes es que no las muestres. Cada imagen que hay en una petición web es un recurso y tiene su propia descarga. Si vas al inspector del navegador podrás ver todas las imágenes que descargues en el apartado de Network.